# Align CSS grid elements

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-grid

I start learning working with the CSS grid. I am making a grid there  is [looking like this](https://jsfiddle.net/9Lcvg5n4/). I need the item 3 and 4 to align with item 1 horizontally.

The height on all items should give 700px, so that part should fit. I am thinking if I am doing something wrong in the code regarding the rows and columns?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(11, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

.wrapper>div {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 1em;
}

.wrapper>div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.item1 {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  grid-column: 1/6;
  height: 700px;
}

.item2 {
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  grid-column: 6/12;
  height: 340px;
}

.item3 {
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  grid-column: 6/9;
  height: 350px;
}

.item4 {
  grid-row: 2/3;
  grid-column: 9/12;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item1">
    This is item 1
  </div>
  <div class="item2">
    This is item 2
  </div>
  <div class="item3">
    This is item 3
  </div>
  <div class="item4">
    This is item 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of changes should help. Firstly, change the `grid-gap` on the `wrapper` from `1em` to `10px`. This helps with the gap issue with 1em usually being 16px by default. Then just add `box-sizing: border-box;` to the `.wrapper > div`.

Here's a working example:

```css
.wrapper {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(11,1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
} 

.wrapper > div {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.item1 {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  grid-column: 1/6;
  height: 700px;
}
.item2 {
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  grid-column: 6/12;
  height: 340px;
}
.item3 {
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  grid-column: 6/9;
  height: 350px;
} 
.item4 {
  grid-row:2/3;
  grid-column: 9/12;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="item1">
      This is item 1
    </div>
    <div class="item2">
      This is item 2
    </div>
    <div class="item3">
      This is item 3
    </div>
    <div class="item4">
      This is item 4
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I can see that is working. But I think I am getting problems if I want to build more grids. Fx if I want a new row with 2 columns. The height of the item is gonna be 400px. Isnt that gonna be problematic when I set the height on the wrapper? https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=501690173342

Answer (score 1):

Your problem was the `padding:1em` on each of the grid elements. This makes them bigger than you expect.

I've amended your example below. I hope this helps :-)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(11, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

.wrapper > div {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 1em;
}
.wrapper > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.item1 {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  grid-column: 1/6;
  height: 700px;
}
.item2 {
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  grid-column: 6/12;
}
.item3 {
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  grid-column: 6/9;
}
.item4 {
  grid-row: 2/3;
  grid-column: 9/12;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item1">This is item 1</div>
  <div class="item2">This is item 2</div>
  <div class="item3">This is item 3</div>
  <div class="item4">This is item 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I can see that is working. But I think I am getting problems if I want to build more grids. Fx if I want a new row with 2 columns. The height of the item is gonna be 400px. Isnt that gonna be problematic when I set the height on the wrapper? https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=501690173342

Comment: @McDuck4 I see what you mean :-) I've amended my answer with the new information. If you remove the heights for all elements except the `.item1`. Then you'll be able to add more underneath without limiting the wrapper.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer. So the first column will control the height? So I can also use this for other grid elements?

Comment: It's just the largest element on that row, so the elements on the other side will grow to whatever that size is. If you add more rows underneath, then just add a height for that item too. You could also use `grid-template-rows` to help you make each row a different size.